# How can I lower a cast iron downspout safely?

Tags: plumbing

I live in a two story house from 1949. The cast iron guttering down pipe is rusted through about 1 meter from the bottom. My plan was to cut the section that was rusted out and replace it with some plastic. However after I cut the bottom the one of the clips that tie it to the house have fallen out. It is only held up now by the pipe below the area I cut. I am happy to replace the whole thing however is there a way to get it to fall without it killing me? It looks like it will drop in two sections, the first is about 3 meters and the last meter at the top will come down after. The pin is precarious on the top, which makes be think when that bottom bit goes that section will follow. Is there a way to make it more safe when removing it?

Comment: One of those man lifts and take it down from the top down.  60 to 100ft long ropes, but even at the end of the ropes you might get by shrapnel when the pipes break on hitting the ground.

Comment: Photos would really help

Comment: Do you have a ladder tall enough to get to the top?  How are you going to replace the iron. pipe?  If calling a professional, have them do the demo removal too.  If you are sure you are doing this yourself we need more info about the area around the pipe.  As Armand said...PICS are needed

Comment: @RMDman   A ladder near 20 plus feet of potentially  loose cast iron pipe, not my idea of fun.

Comment: At this point it really seems like hiring help (with equipment) before it kills you or someone else might be wise.

Comment: Why can't you strap it up above the cut?

Comment: Go purchase a "riser clamp" from your big box store in the plumbing area. Attach it to the pipe and build something to hold the clamp up

Comment: @crip659: over 10 feet and I would start thinking about renting scaffolding rather than ladders. Or hire someone. Height plus weight, I'd go for the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Safety first

To keep the pipe from falling on you, drill a hole through the pipe at the top and in the middle. Run a steel cable through it and attach it to a hand winch secured near the top of the pipe to the building structure with steel cable clamps, so you can loosen and lower when done with the pipe cutting.